# best way to preventing form resubmission of codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Always confused about form resubmission . I know Header and session  are the right way. But I don't know how can I proper use in codeigniter. Suppose

For single insert and update query

```
    $this->db->query(' insert/up query');
    $this->session->set_flashdata('success_message','successfully inserted');
    redirect('my_contoller/home/index');
```

For pass `$data` array

```
$data['pass_data']="some array elements";
$this->session->set_flashdata('pass_data_from_flash_data',$data['pass_data']);
redirect('my_contoller/home/index',$data);
```

If above technique are right how can I pass  query's data for retrieving. Suppose I have a query which return many data. Such as

```
 $query = $this->db->query(" a query which return large data");
 $data['return_large_result']=$query->result_array();
```

I just confused to using `set_flashdata` function. Is the right way?

Answer (score 1):

The above method mentioned you are using is a [valid web development design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). Codeigniter is a bit messy for this method but essentially yes it is the right way within Codeigniter.

Other frameworks such as Laravel support this feature better, allowing you to access old input via `Input::old()` amongst other methods.

Comment: but if data is larger then session memory, how can I manage. i dont know about CI flash data memory . But 1 question will have been If data is more then over thousand array?

Comment: Then you need to use a different storage method such as storing it temporarily in a file, database or a different data store with a pointer to this in a session. These cases aren't common so these sorts of forms might not use the `POST/REDIRECT/GET` method.